# Visual Studio 2012 error: Assertion Failed

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, allegro5

I am using Vc++(2012) with allegro 5.0.7. and following [this link](http://www.anothergames.com/book/allegro?page=3) for tutorials.

I get assertion Failed error when I compiled the code present at the above given link. Here is [a snapshot of my error](http://www.anothergames.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=761&p=1045#p1045).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized and not likely to help future visitors.

Comment: This question is missing an [mcve], so I will try voting to close it again. Questions need to be self-contained here in order to remain useful for other readers over the long term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a null bitmap. The most common reason is you are running your program from a directory that you are not expecting, causing your relative paths to fail.

Read and follow the advice [of this article](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Loading_Resources_(Troubleshooting)) to solve the issue.